# F-Curve Curve Selection

Tags: animation

I have the hardest time adjusting handles and selecting specifics curves in the f-curve. Often times 2-3 vertices will be on top of each other making it hard to select the right one.

Any workflow tips? Any way to hide other handles or only show the selected?

Comment: In the graph editor it's wise to block out all axis channels not being adjusted.  Have just the one available.  The padlocks at left will do this.  Also the eye icons can remove unwanted channels altogether.  You can zoom up to maximum by centering the cursor on the keyframe required with the numpad's plus key. (+)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I wish the control click to focus worked on the eyes in f-curve like it does in the outliner.

Comment: Another clue might be to use the arrow and ghost icons at the bottom.  In the Dopesheet the arrows allows just the object(s) selected to show and the ghost will allow it's inclusion even when the Outliner's eye icon has it switched to invisible.  I might be wrong here, but I seem to remember this applying to the graph editor as well.  (currently using Vers 2.77a)

Comment: oh, I'll check that, that would be amazing